# GetText compare

Tags: android, android-edittext

So i have a EditText field, which i want to, check if the age is above and under my limits.

```
if (Integer.parseInt(age.getText().toString()) < 18 && Integer.parseInt(age.getText().toString()) >= 0)
```

But also, i want to simply check if the field is empty, for what i used.

else if (age.getText().toString().isEmpty())

Unluckly this one is not working, i think it sort of get in to conflict with the first one or something, because i tried with just one condition of both, and it works..
I also tried to store in String variable the method to check isEmpty(), and also in int one, to do the age comparation, but it still not working.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The code should be:

```
if (age.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()){
    //The EditText field is empty
}else{
    try{
        if (Integer.parseInt(age.getText().toString().trim()) < 18 && Integer.parseInt(age.getText().toString().trim()) >= 0){
            //Your code here
        }else{
            //Input value is over 18 or under 0
        }
    }catch(Exception ex){
        //There was an error parsing the input (if your user writes letters, parseInt fails)
    }
}
```